# writing to start of a file with NSIS

Tags: nsis

How to write to the very start of a file with NSIS ?
I have a large text file and so can't use `FileRead` as it looks to have a limit of 1024 characters.
I tried using `FileSeek` to set the pointer -30 from the beginning of the file but I guess that's not possible and so it doesn't work.

If I use `FileWrite` as it is , it writes to the start of the file deleting as many characters 
 as it writes from the top of the file.

Any help ?

Comment: The overwrite behavior is normal, that's how most IO works. If you don't want to overwrite you have to move the old content first...

Answer (score 0):

You could use this script to [write to a specified line number](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Write_to_text_file_line_number) from the [Text Files Manipulation Functions](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Category%3aText_Files_Manipulation_Functions). The 1024 character limit was caused by the maximum string length of the default NSIS build (there's a [special build](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Special_Builds) extending the limit)

Comment: `FileWriteLine` doesn't work for me. It deletes all existing data and instead writes what I want it to write 2 times . Here is the code - http://pastebin.com/1WSqyA9V

Answer (score 0):

The 'brute force' method should work.

So you can do it like this (tested):

```
FileOpen $0 "SourceFile.txt" r
FileOpen $1 "TargetFile.txt" w

; First add the new text
FileWrite $1 "The Text to add to the start of the file."

; Copy File byte by byte
loop:
  ClearErrors
  FileReadByte $0 $2
  IfErrors exit
  FileWriteByte $1 $2
  Goto loop

exit:
  FileClose $0
  FileClose $1
```

If you need the target file in place of the source file you can move it afterwards with help of the macro [MoveFileFolder](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/MoveFileFolder).